# Which version of Quartz is compatible with Spring 2.5.6

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, jboss6.x

Currently my application is using Spring 2.5.6 and opensymphony.quartz-1.6.1 and is deployed on JBoss6.

I have been given task to upgrade the quartz version if possible.
But when i try to do so with any stable version like 1.8.6 or 2.0.2 or 2.2.0 - I get following error :

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: ThreadPool class 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' could not be instantiated. 
[See nested exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool cannot be cast to org.quartz.spi.ThreadPool]
```

There is no direct reference given to ThreadPool in code.
Is it due to any class clashes ?

I also oberved the thing as - on upgrading the version - the groupid also changes to 'org.quartz-scheduler' from 'opensymphony.quartz'.
Is it because 2.5.6 doesn't supports greater quartz versions ?

Thanks
Dhananjay

Comment: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?75833-Quartz-classCastException might help

Comment: tried, but didn't work :(